# ATmega48PA power consumption during EEPROM write

Tags: avr, low-power, eeprom

**PLEASE, PLEASE!** My question is about power consumption of the CPU during EEPROM write **NOT** about the power supply! PLEASE! Thank you!

I have a device (ATmega48PA) powered through a 150k resistor directly from the line (with regulation of course!):

[image]

In more details (however this is FAR from the question and I don't know why so many people discussing the power supply schematic and NOT the question I asked):

[image]

I've estimated the consumption of the CPU itself about 300-400 uA which looked realistic with 2.5V VCC and 1M frequency.

However after I tried to write some data to CPU's EEPROM VCC goes dramatically down (generating BOD reset).
After some investigation I realized that the current goes to 7 mA (and the current growing dramatically further if VCC higher).

I tried to find any information in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/8161s.pdf), but the only thing I found was this chart (on page 538):

[image]

Which is not really comply with my experience (and it looks like FLASH programming, not EEPROM).

So what is the reality of the current consumption of CPU during EEPROM write? And is it possible to reduce it?

Comment: Is there a reason you're powering the device through a large resistor in the first place?

Comment: It is actually a terrible idea.

Comment: @NickJohnson of course! If the resistor will be smaller (in Ohms) it becomes pretty hot! And the device can become a energy inefficient despite the fact it is a micropower. Why I don't use any SMPS solutions: device should be extremely cheap and small.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Which idea?

Comment: @RomanMatveev powering the device through a resistor is a terrible idea. Get a tiny linear regulator instead. http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=TC1014 < 50 cents in single quantities from digikey.

Comment: @RomanMatveev What's wrong with an LDO? You say it gets hot; is this resistor in series with VCC, or is it a resistor divider?

Comment: Also, "directly from the line" - which line? Hopefully not a mains line?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have an LDO in the schematic. I just supposed that this is obvious, sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @pjc50, yes: it is mains.

Comment: You DO NOT have an LDO in the circuit.  You have a shunt regulator.

Comment: That circuit screams "death to all users."  Is this thing going to be sealed up so that no one could possibly, conceivably ever, really never, never no way touch any electrical part of the circuit when in operation?

Comment: @JRE, I have an LDO, please see my question I have added some details (why discussing this but not the question I asked?). And 'yes' I aware of the danger - the device is well sealed.

Comment: So, you have a shunt regulator followed by an LDO. Step 1 would be to eliminate the shunt regulator so you can get more power without wasting most of it. And incidentally reduce the risk of electrocution in the first place.

Comment: People are asking about your power regulation because the question you asked 'smells' like your problem isn't what you think it is - in this case, the issue only arises because you're unable to draw more than a tiny amount of power without your rail browning out.

Comment: Repeat: You DO NOT have an LDO, even with the additional schematic.  You have a 7805 (L78L05) which has a dropout of 1.7V, which doesn't qualify as low.  You have a linear regulator, and are following the really bizarre habit people have gotten into of calling all linear regulators LDO (Low Drop Out) even when (as in the case of the 7805) they cannot be considered low dropout at all.

Answer (score 1):

The [complete datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2545.pdf) for the ATMega48 has more details on power consumption, but nothing specific to EEPROM write. It's not unusual that writing to EEPROM would take a lot more current than regular operation, however.

Instead of powering your AVR via a large resistor, you should use a linear regulator so its input voltage doesn't depend directly on the current it consumes.

Comment: Please see my edited original question for clarification regarding the power supply schematic.

Comment: I've done my best to answer your original question given what little information the manufacturer provides. You're not likely to find more information from official sources; if you want exact figures you'll have to characterize the device yourself.